# Difference between tf.train.shuffle_batch_join and tf.train.shuffle_batch

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, pipeline

Looking at both function signatures, with arguments

```
tf.train.shuffle_batch_join(
tensors_list,
batch_size,
capacity,
min_after_dequeue,
seed=None,
enqueue_many=False,
shapes=None,
allow_smaller_final_batch=False,
shared_name=None,
name=None
)
```

and

```
tf.train.shuffle_batch(
tensors,
batch_size,
capacity,
min_after_dequeue,
num_threads=1,
seed=None,
enqueue_many=False,
shapes=None,
allow_smaller_final_batch=False,
shared_name=None,
name=None
)
```

the only difference is among the atguments is `num_threads` that denotes intuitively that `tf.train.shuffle_batch` could be processed with multiple threads or processes, Except that,  they seem to do pretty much the same work.

I was wondering if there is a fundamental difference on which someone might choose one over the other except multiprocessing of batches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the shuffle_batch_join TF documentation :

> The tensors_list argument is a list of tuples of tensors, or a list of dictionaries of tensors. Each element in the list is treated similarly to the tensors argument of tf.train.shuffle_batch().

Basically, shuffle_batch_join expects to:

- Receive a list of tensors
- Perform shuffle_batch on each member of the list
- Return a list of tensors with the same number and types as tensors_list[i].

Be aware that if you use shuffle_batch_join :

> len(tensors_list) threads will be started, with thread i enqueuing the tensors from tensors_list[i]. tensors_list[i1][j] must match tensors_list[i2][j] in type and shape, except in the first dimension if enqueue_many is true.

[Here is a link to the doc.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/shuffle_batch_join)

Comment: I think I ve read the docs, and I didn't see so much difference, except in function arguments as if one overloads the other,my question was what is the difference in using one over other?performance?my initial thinking was batch shuffle instead of element wise shuflle by batch? The docs says the exact same thing for each parameter

Comment: Have a look at [this doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/programmers_guide/reading_data). Basically, shuffle_batch_join is preferred if you have multiple readers and want to shuffle between files.